# twitter login not working on my server

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

When I try to login from server

```
[http_code] => 401
[url] => https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
[host] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
[timeout] => 30
[connecttimeout] => 30
[ssl_verifypeer] => 
[format] => json
[decode_json] => 1
[http_info] => Array
    (.....
```

When I try to login from my Localhost its working fine

```
[http_code] => 200
[url] => https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
[host] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
[timeout] => 30
[connecttimeout] => 30
[ssl_verifypeer] => 
[format] => json
[decode_json] => 1
[http_info] => Array
    (.....
```

Can anyone help me. My `twitter_consumer_token` and `twitter_consumer_secret` are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your server time has not set properly